# Spring oauth2 don't authentify user correctly

Tags: angular, shibboleth, spring-oauth2

I have an Angular app that log to my backend throught oauth2 using authrozation code flow.

When the user login he's redirected to a login page (shiboleth) and after the app continue the flow asking for an access token by calling the /oauht/token URL.

this process work when in dev mode bu when I deployed the application I'm getting an error 403 when calling the /oauth/token URL.

After debugging I found out that error in the logs :

```
Jul 02 12:32:30 test-2 java[20962]: 2019-07-02 12:32:30.115 DEBUG 20962 --- [.1-16100-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token; Attributes: [hasAnyAuthority('TRUSTED_CLIENT')]
Jul 02 12:32:30 test-2 java[20962]: 2019-07-02 12:32:30.115 DEBUG 20962 --- [.1-16100-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: DLCM Authentication [user=ch.dmm.service.DMMUserDetails@775e4c20, authenticated=true]
Jul 02 12:36:48 test-2 java[20962]: 2019-07-02 12:36:48.061 DEBUG 20962 --- [.1-16100-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@88532f3, returned: -1
Jul 02 12:36:48 test-2 java[20962]: 2019-07-02 12:36:48.066 DEBUG 20962 --- [.1-16100-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

as showed in the logs, spring is verifiying if the USER hasAnyAuthority !! and here is the probelem, he should do this verification on the client app ( angular ) and not the USER !!

When debugging in dev mode the process is done correctly !!

I don't understand why ?

```java
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  ShibAuthenticationProvider shibAuthenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProvider oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  BasicClientAuthenticationProvider basicClientAuthenticationProvider;

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(DLCMConstants.getPublicUrls()).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/check_token").hasAnyAuthority(RoleApplication.TRUSTED_CLIENT)
        .antMatchers("/oauth/revoke_token").hasAnyAuthority(RoleApplication.TRUSTED_CLIENT)
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").hasAnyAuthority(RoleApplication.TRUSTED_CLIENT)
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
      .httpBasic()
        .and()
      .authenticationProvider(basicClientAuthenticationProvider)
      .authenticationProvider(oAuth2ClientAuthenticationProvider)
      .authenticationProvider(shibAuthenticationProvider)
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
      .csrf()
        .disable();
    // @formatter:on
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add deployed application URL into OAuth2 client urls.

Comment: What do you mean by adding deployed app URL to Oauth2 client urls ?

Comment: I mean put you application URL as part of your `RoleApplication.TRUSTED_CLIENT` check, so that it can allow token request from that client

Comment: My App has the TRUSTED_CLIENT role and the problem is that spring is identifying the user against instead of the Oauth2ClientUserDetails